# Strange interaction between beamer and tcolorbox

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox

I have been trying to figure out why isn't the text color in a titleless `tcolorbox` frame rendered black in some cases in a `beamer` presentation. This occurs only with certain themes (Madrid, Ilmenau, Copenahagen, ...).

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    This is a text that should have been black.
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The second slide is rendered thus:

[image]

However, if I add a title to the `tcolorbox` frame, the text color turns out black. Also, and strangely enough, *if I remove the presentation's titlepage*, the text color is also rendered black. Like so:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    This is a text that should have been black.
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which is rendered:

[image]

Any ideas as to what might be going on in here?

Comment: The white color seems to leak out from block with the title. But I'm not quite sure if it is a bug or an incompability -- after all the color box of beamer works fine and beamer needs some special code to transport colors between slides. You can reset the color with \normalcolor in the tcolorbox.

Comment: I think, the problem are the rounded beamer boxes. I recently saw a question where the first of two columns vanished after a `beamercolorbox` , but unfortunately I cannot find this question anymore

Comment: See https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/363 Sounds like it is fixed in the latest version, can you try to update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour is due to a [bug](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/363) in `beamer` which is fixed
in the `v3.41` release. Where possible, you should [update your TeX
distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) to install the
current release. If this is not possible, for example if you want to
change only this one package or where you do not have the privileges
to update the entire distribution, you will need to [install the
package locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137).  This option should be considered a last resort, since for more complex packages there may be package dependencies that will make local installation more complicated and error-prone.

As a temporary workaround, until this version is available from ctan, you can place the two files

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/d8541c78ed3744501f515de46dab8373e41991ea/base/beamerbaseoverlay.sty
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/d8541c78ed3744501f515de46dab8373e41991ea/base/beamerbasecolor.sty

in the folder of your .tex file and your text is black again

[image]