# How to avoid problems with the JuanLesPins theme and textsc?

Tags: beamer, small-caps, themes

I'm preparing a presentation and figured out that some text disappears or has a wrong color. Below you'll find a MWE. If you comment out the `JuanLesPins` theme the text with the `\textsc` command will appear or disappear:

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
\title{Foo}
\author{Bar}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage{}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Sets}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
      \textsc{Georg Cantor} is the founder of set theory and he said:
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
      baz
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Can you tell what the reason for this behaviour is and how this can be corrected?

Comment: Very strange - it requires the combination of colorthemes `whale` and `orchid`, the innertheme `rounded` and occurs only on the first frame after `\titlepage` has been issued, only inside the first column and applies to any text there.

Answer (score 3):

This is very strange.  The theme `JuanLesPins` only loads a combination of standard themes with standard options.  Commenting them out shows that the following is enough to reproduce the problem at that it only occurs in the first column of the first slide after the `\titlepage` and has nothing to with the `\textsc`:

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}

\title{Foo}
\author{Bar}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Sets}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
      foo
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
      baz
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Sets}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
      foo
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
      baz
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Sets}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
      foo
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
      baz
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A work around is to add a dummy column to that slide

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Sets}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0pt}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
      foo
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
      baz
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: beamer bug, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350309/strange-interaction-between-beamer-and-tcolorbox/350437